# How to upload contract metadata to Swarm from command line?

Tags: contract-deployment, swarm

I'm running a geth node in a private network, and running swarm in singleton mode on that network. I'm deploying contracts via JSON-RPC; I'm not using JavaScript.

I run the command `solc --optimize --metadata --bin -o . ./coin.sol` which produces the files `Coin_metadata.json` and `Coin.bin`

The file `Coin.bin` contains the string:

```
60606040...a165627a7a723058208686fb331b117b51a664d9295258b00944f066540bfda4eef32934b197d5cbf60029
```

Solidity [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/metadata.html#encoding-of-the-metadata-hash-in-the-bytecode) says

> So in order to retrieve the data, the end of the deployed bytecode can
>   be checked to match that pattern and use the Swarm hash to retrieve
>   the file.

So, the **Swarm hash** is

```
8686fb331b117b51a664d9295258b00944f066540bfda4eef32934b197d5cbf6
```

My question is: What **content** must I upload to Swarm, via command line, to get exactly the previous hash?

I've upload all files individually and the directory containing them, but any upload produces the previous hash.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Playing a bit more with Swarm, I found the swarm's option needed to upload the metadata and return the required hash:

```
swarm --manifest=false up Coin_meta.json
```